Group_Concat() when is null, I get error 1064
I have the following query in MySQL 8.0:
set 
  @userid = 'XXX';
set 
  @lastdate = '2024-09-30';
SET 
  @sql = null;
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT CONCAT(
      'Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = ''', 
      Checkedby, 
      ''' THEN Checkedby ELSE 0 END) AS ''', 
      CONCAT(
        IFNULL(FirstName, ''), 
        ' ', 
        IFNULL(LastName, '')
      ), 
      ''''
    )
  ) into @sql 
FROM 
  aspnetusers A 
  join userinfo U on A.Id = U.id 
  left join bookings B ON A.Id = B.CheckedBy 
where 
  (
    ParentId = @userid 
    OR A.Id = @userid
  ) 
  and year(Checkin)= year(@lastdate) 
  and B.UserID = @userid 
  and month(Checkin)= month(@lastdate);
SET 
  @sql = CONCAT (
    'SELECT  Y.*, R.* 
FROM 
(SELECT day(Checkin) as DayX, 
IFNULL(count(IFNULL(Checkin,0)),0) as Total, ', 
    @sql, '
FROM aspnetusers A join userinfo U on A.Id=U.id left join bookings B ON A.Id=B.CheckedBy 
where year(Checkin)= year(@lastdate) and B.UserID= @userid and month(Checkin)= month(@lastdate) 
group by day(Checkin) 
) R right JOIN 
 (select day(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY) as Day
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
   where year(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY)=year(@lastdate) and month(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY)=month(@lastdate)
    order by Day) Y on R.DayX = Y.Day 
    GROUP BY Y.Day, R.Total order by Y.Day'
  );
PREPARE stmt 
FROM 
  @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


the result is the following:
result wo error
if I change the date, I get the following error:

11:29:17    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1    0.000 sec

It seems that when the first query becomes null, I get the error, but I don't know how to correct it.
If someone has a simpler method, it would be great.
PS. I will use this query in a chart and would be also nice to show all users and their values (if its null then 0). I wrote the above script in MySQL, but in the feature I think I will convert all the queries to MariaDB.
Thanks,
Steve
I tried IFNULL and COALESCE but don't seem to work.
EDIT:

WORKING:
set @lastdate = '2024-09-30';
-- 0 @sql value
    Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = '0bb63911-cc7b-4db0-bd33-b30edbc27a27' THEN Checkedby ELSE 0 END) AS 'Meggie1 Simpson',Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = '97c73a4d-11b2-4492-a234-90b4cbff86c5' THEN Checkedby ELSE 0 END) AS 'MOLNAR ISTVAN'
    -- 1 after exec
    SELECT  Y.*, R.* 
    FROM 
    (SELECT day(Checkin) as DayX, 
    IFNULL(count(IFNULL(Checkin,0)),0) as Total, Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = '0bb63911-cc7b-4db0-bd33-b30edbc27a27' THEN Checkedby ELSE 0 END) AS 'Meggie1 Simpson',Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = '97c73a4d-11b2-4492-a234-90b4cbff86c5' THEN Checkedby ELSE 0 END) AS 'MOLNAR ISTVAN'
    FROM aspnetusers A join userinfo U on A.Id=U.id left join bookings B ON A.Id=B.CheckedBy 
    where year(Checkin)= year(@lastdate) and B.UserID= @userid and month(Checkin)= month(@lastdate) 
    group by day(Checkin) 
    ) R right JOIN 
     (select day(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY) as Day
        from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
        cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
        cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
       where year(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY)=year(@lastdate) and month(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY)=month(@lastdate)
        order by Day) Y on R.DayX = Y.Day 
        GROUP BY Y.Day, R.Total order by Y.Day
        -- 2 table name:
        GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
          'Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = ''', 
          Checkedby, 
          ''' THEN Checkedby ELSE 0 END) AS ''', 
          CONCAT(
            IFNULL(FirstName, ''), 
            ' ', 
            IFNULL(LastName, '')
          ), 
          ''''
        ): 
-- 3 result
Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = '0bb63911-cc7b-4db0-bd33-b30edbc27a27' THEN Checkedby ELSE 0 END) AS 'Meggie1 Simpson',Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = '97c73a4d-11b2-4492-a234-90b4cbff86c5' THEN Checkedby ELSE 0 END) AS 'MOLNAR ISTVAN'


NOT WORKING:
set @lastdate = '2024-10-31';
-- 2 table name:
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
          'Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = ''', 
          Checkedby, 
          ''' THEN Checkedby ELSE 0 END) AS ''', 
          CONCAT(
            IFNULL(FirstName, ''), 
            ' ', 
            IFNULL(LastName, '')
          ), 
          ''''
        ): 
-- 3 result
Null

Edit:
set  @userid = '97c73a4d-11b2-4492-a234-90b4cbXXXX';
set @lastdate = '2024-09-30';//OK - 2024-10-31 //NOK
SET @sql=null;

SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT CONCAT(
      'Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = ''', 
      Checkedby, 
      ''' THEN Checkedby END) AS ''', 
      CONCAT(IFNULL(FirstName,''), ' ', IFNULL(LastName,'')), 
      ''''
    )
  ) into @sql
FROM aspnetusers A left join userinfo U on A.Id=U.id left join bookings B ON A.Id=B.CheckedBy
where  year(Checkin)= year(@lastdate) and month(Checkin)= month(@lastdate);

select @sql;

SET @sql = CONCAT ('SELECT  Y.*, R.* 
FROM 
(SELECT day(Checkin) as DayX, 
IFNULL(count(IFNULL(Checkin,0)),0) as Total, ',@sql,'
FROM aspnetusers A join userinfo U on A.Id=U.id left join bookings B ON A.Id=B.CheckedBy 
where year(Checkin)= year(@lastdate) and month(Checkin)= month(@lastdate) 
group by day(Checkin) 
) R right JOIN 
 (select day(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY) as Day
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
   where year(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY)=year(@lastdate) and month(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY)=month(@lastdate)
    order by Day) Y on R.DayX = Y.Day 
    GROUP BY Y.Day, R.Total order by Y.Day');

select @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
select @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

On "2024-09-30" - Working:
result 1 img
Result 1:
Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = '0bb63911-cc7b-4db0-bd33-b30edbc27a07' THEN Checkedby END) AS 'Meggie1 Simpson',Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = '97c73a4d-11b2-4492-a234-90b4cbff36c5' THEN Checkedby END) AS 'MOLNAR ISTVAN'

Result2:
SELECT  Y.*, R.* 
FROM 
(SELECT day(Checkin) as DayX, 
IFNULL(count(IFNULL(Checkin,0)),0) as Total, Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = '0bb63911-cc7b-4db0-bd33-b30edbc27a07' THEN Checkedby END) AS 'Meggie1 Simpson',Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = '97c73a4d-11b2-4492-a234-90b4cbff36c5' THEN Checkedby END) AS 'MOLNAR ISTVAN'
FROM aspnetusers A join userinfo U on A.Id=U.id left join bookings B ON A.Id=B.CheckedBy 
where year(Checkin)= year(@lastdate) and month(Checkin)= month(@lastdate) 
group by day(Checkin) 
) R right JOIN 
 (select day(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY) as Day
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
   where year(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY)=year(@lastdate) and month(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY)=month(@lastdate)
    order by Day) Y on R.DayX = Y.Day 
    GROUP BY Y.Day, R.Total order by Y.Day

Result 3:
SELECT  Y.*, R.* 
FROM 
(SELECT day(Checkin) as DayX, 
IFNULL(count(IFNULL(Checkin,0)),0) as Total, Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = '0bb63911-cc7b-4db0-bd33-b30edbc27a07' THEN Checkedby END) AS 'Meggie1 Simpson',Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = '97c73a4d-11b2-4492-a234-90b4cbff36c5' THEN Checkedby END) AS 'MOLNAR ISTVAN'
FROM aspnetusers A join userinfo U on A.Id=U.id left join bookings B ON A.Id=B.CheckedBy 
where year(Checkin)= year(@lastdate) and month(Checkin)= month(@lastdate) 
group by day(Checkin) 
) R right JOIN 
 (select day(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY) as Day
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
   where year(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY)=year(@lastdate) and month(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY)=month(@lastdate)
    order by Day) Y on R.DayX = Y.Day 
    GROUP BY Y.Day, R.Total order by Y.Day

Result 4:
The working table (image above)
On "2024-10-31" - Not Working:
Result 1:
NULL
result1 img
Result2:
NULL
result2 img

Provide the value of @sql variable when it causes an error.

@Akina I added code when the code is working and also from not working

?? None shown value is valid SQL code which can be processed by PREPARE..

We need to see the final value of @sql after you concatenate it into the SELECT query.

@Barmar I attached results and images for working and not working query.

FYI, you don't need to use CONCAT() inside GROUP_CONCAT(). If you give it multiple arguments, it automatically concatenates them.

What do the numbers in "Result 1", "Result 2", etc. refer to? What are they the results of? Result 2 and Result 3 look the same to me, am I missing something?

@Barmar I think I found the problem: I the group_concat part I changed the where clause to where    (     ParentId = @userid      OR A.Id = @userid   )    and B.UserID = @userid ; and now it seems to work, I deleted this part: year(Checkin)= year(@lastdate) and month(Checkin)= month(@lastdate)

You mean you removed the year and month checks?

@Barmar Now I'm trying to to replace the null values. If you have any tips, that would be awesome!

@Barmar Can you please help me setting the IFNULL ( for changing nulls to 0 )? Thanks advanced.

@Akina  If you have any tips how to solve the null problem, that would be great !

I think what you want is IFNULL(COUNT(...), 0) to return 0 when there are no values to count.
